# How to add correct time of event in EventKit (swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I am coming to a minor issue where when I implemented a logic to add an event every other friday. But, for some reason the time it is wrong. It always shows 12:00AM by default. Is there a way to set the time of the event to 6:30PM? I need some help to solve this minor issue. I checked the `EventKit` documentation. But got stuck. thanks for the help.

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

class EducationPillarViewController: UIViewController {



     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func addEventToCalendar(title: String, description: String?, startDate: Date, endDate: Date, completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: NSError?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()

        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                event.title = title
                event.startDate = startDate
                event.endDate = endDate
                event.notes = description
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                do {
                    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)

                } catch let e as NSError {
                    completion?(false, e)
                    return

                }
                completion?(true, nil)

            } else {
                completion?(false, error as NSError?)
            }
        })
    }



    @IBAction func MyStudyButtonWasTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My Study", message:"Every other Fridays at 6:30PM ", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        let addtocalendarAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add to Calendar", style: .default, handler: someHandler)


        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        alertController.addAction(addtocalendarAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

    func someHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!) {

    let friday = EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.friday)


        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

      let startWeek = Date().startOfWeek
        let endWeek = Date().endOfWeek



   EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .weekly, interval: 2, daysOfTheWeek: [friday], daysOfTheMonth: nil, monthsOfTheYear: nil, weeksOfTheYear: nil, daysOfTheYear: nil, setPositions: nil, end: nil)


    addEventToCalendar(title: "My Study", description: "Every Other Fridays", startDate: startWeek!, endDate: endWeek!)


    let alertControlller = UIAlertController(title: "My Study", message: "My Study event has been added to your calendar", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertControlller.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertControlller, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }




}

extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let friday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: friday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let friday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 5, to: friday)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another function to the extension Date block

```
public func setTime(hour: Int, min: Int, sec: Int) -> Date? {
        let x: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        let cal = Calendar.current
        var components = cal.dateComponents(x, from: self)


        components.hour = hour
        components.minute = min
        components.second = sec

        return cal.date(from: components)
    }
```

Then once you've done that chagne your line of code that declares the startWeek variable `let startWeek = Date().startOfWeek` to `var startWeek = Date().startOfWeek`.Then below that line put `startWeek = startWeek?.setTime(hour: 12, min: 30, sec: 00)`.

Finally change the endWeek variable

`var endWeek = Date().endOfWeek
endWeek = endweek?.setTime(hour: 13, min: 30, sec: 00)`

Comment: Hey @Spencer, I followed the way you said to implement. But... it still shows 12:00AM.

Comment: it says `Result of call to 'setTime(hour:min:sec:)' is unused`

Comment: My bad, Your code should be changed to `var startWeek = Date().startOfWeek` instead of let
and below that `startWeek =  startWeek?.setTime(hour: 12, min: 30, sec: 00)` I've also edited my original answer

Comment: alright. so, I implement your code and now I dont see my event being created. hmm...

Comment: Try doing the same thing with endWeek except setting the hour to 13 instead of twelve so it should look like this                                                                                               `var endWeek = Date().endOfWeek` and `endWeek = endWeek?.setTime(hour: 13, min: 30, sec: 00)`. This happened since your endWeek is now before your startWeek time hence no event being created since it can't end before it has started.

Comment: That was weird. it started working. Also, one last thing how can I slightly change from AM to PM?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by slightly change from AM to PM?

Comment: never mind. I just did `startWeek = startWeek?.setTime(hour: 18, min: 30, sec: 00)` to get 6:30PM. thank you for your help.